# Can I connect a keyboard via micro-usb to a smartphone which doesn't support OTG?

Tags: usb-on-the-go, external-keyboard

My phone has no OTG support. A standard USB keyboard connected using an OTG cable doesn't work or even get recognized. Would a keyboard which instead connects via micro-usb work? Or would the phone require OTG support for that too?

The version of Android is 5.1.1. The phone is not rooted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A keyboard with micro-USB connector is simply the combination of a keyboard with an OTG adapter, therefore this will not help you if your device has no USB OTG support.

If you want to connect a keyboard to your Android phone instead you may try to use a Bluetooth keyboard.

Comment: Since the lack of OTG support can be summarized in "the phone's micro-USB port does not deliver power", couldn't OP solve the issue with an Y cable?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Is that all that lack of OTG support entails though? AFAIK, there is usually something lacking in the electonics/built-in software of a phone.

Comment: @386blastprocessing The kernel (software) must support OTG and the micro-USB port (hardware) must supply energy. If one of the conditions is not met, then OTG won't work. Custom kernels might implement OTG support but, as far as I know, there's no way to force a micro-USB port to supply energy, if the manufacturer didn't build it to do so.